# I have a problem with this url_launcher pluging in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm working on a project that uses url_launcher, it works just fine on my device although it throws these errors and when I try to built the apk app it throws this error

```
    Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: D:\Programs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\webview_media-0.1.2\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\webviewflutter\FlutterWebView.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: D:\Programs\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.4.10\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
```

What is the problem and how can I overcome it, thanks.

```
my pubspec.yamel 


version: 1.0.0+1

environment:
  sdk: ">=2.1.0 <3.0.0"

dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  bot_toast: ^3.0.0
  url_launcher: ^5.4.10
  device_preview: ^0.4.5
  flutter_launcher_icons: ^0.7.5
  cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
  rflutter_alert: ^1.0.3
  youtube_player_flutter: ^6.1.1
  # animated_text_kit: ^2.0.0
  # google_fonts: ^0.3.2

dev_dependencies:
  flutter_test:
    sdk: flutter
```

Comment: First of all It's note an error.